# How to list all files with a given extension?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I want to list all files in the current directory that have the exension .zip or .xml.

How can I grep for .xml or .zip extension that also begin with a specific pattern in linux command line?

Let's assume

```
xyz[something random].[zip|xml]
```

Comment: Is that the filename to search in or the pattern to search for?

Comment: I want to list all files in the current directory that have the exension .zip or .xml